# datetime2 storage size

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, SP2
The [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) says that **datetime2** takes 6, 7 or 8 bytes depending witch precision you use

I need to store a large amount of data in binary form (concatenated values) and I love the idea of using only 6 bytes for each datetime, however when I try:

```
declare @_dt_p0 datetime2(0) = '2012-05-18 11:22:33'
select  CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p0), LEN(CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p0))

declare @_dt_p4 datetime2(4) = '2012-05-18 11:22:33'
select  CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p4), LEN(CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p4))

declare @_dt_p7 datetime2(7) = '2012-05-18 11:22:33'
select  CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p7), LEN(CONVERT(varbinary, @_dt_p7))
```

It's clearly taking one extra byte, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're fussing over a byte per row difference between your calculated length and the actual length, your problem is probably using a database system.

Comment: If you use `datalength` it tells a [different story](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/77713).

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: Actually is 191 bytes per row, since in a varbinary(8000) column I can store 1333 datetimes (6 bytes) instead of 1142 (7 bytes). Regardless, that's not the point of the question.

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson: Thanks Mikael, you are right, please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Well `datalength` also returns 7 on the value converted to varbinary first. Which in my answer I question as a valid test in the first place.

Comment: @ Mikael Eriksson: I just noticed that DATALENGTH was over @_dt_pX, not over the CONVERT()

Comment: @Nick Yes... You don't need to convert it to measure the length. But if you do convert it, datalength will also report one extra byte. If I figure out the reason for a convert to varbinary adding one extra byte I will post an answer. So far I have found that it is the same for both `time` and `datetime2` but not for `datetime`.

Comment: The point I was trying to raise has obviously been lost on you - and your counter examples amplify the point. If you're storing more than a few datetime2 values in a single row, then you're probably using the wrong technology for your problem. If you're storing thousands of datetime2 values and the storage size is the main issue, then you're probably, again, using the wrong technology.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think I can explain why the length / datalength of a varbinary conversion is 7 instead of 6 (Mikael later found that [the convert to varbinary adds the precision as an extra byte](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/12/15/the-internal-storage-of-a-datetime2-value.aspx)), but I don't know why you think that's a valid test anyway. I can confirm that 6 bytes are stored on the page when you are using an actual column (though null overhead for the row will be different depending on whether the column is nullable). How can I prove this?

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.x
(
 d1 DATETIME2(0)  NULL, 
 v1 VARBINARY(32) NULL,
 d2 DATETIME2(0)  NOT NULL, 
 v2 VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL
);

declare @d datetime2(0) = '2012-05-18 11:22:33';

INSERT dbo.x(d1, v1, d2, v2)
SELECT @d, CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), @d), @d, CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), @d);

SELECT DATALENGTH(d1), DATALENGTH(v1), 
       DATALENGTH(d2), DATALENGTH(v2) FROM dbo.x;
```

Results:

```
6    7    6    7
```

So, the datetime2 columns are 6 bytes, but the varbinary columns are 7 bytes. Regardless of nullability. We can look closer by actually inspecting the page. Let's find all the pages in the heap for this table:

```
DBCC IND('tempdb', 'dbo.x', 0);
```

Partial results on my system (yours will be different):

```
PagePID  PageType
283      10
311      1
```

So now let's look at Page 311:

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604, -1);
DBCC PAGE(2, 1, 311, 3);
```

And we can see that the datetime2 columns indeed occupy 6 bytes on the page:

```
Slot 0 Column 1 Offset 0x4 Length 6 Length (physical) 6

d1 = 2012-05-18 11:22:33            

v1 = [Binary data] Slot 0 Column 2 Offset 0x19 Length 7 Length (physical) 7
v1 = 0x00f99f00b0350b               

Slot 0 Column 3 Offset 0xa Length 6 Length (physical) 6

d2 = 2012-05-18 11:22:33            

v2 = [Binary data] Slot 0 Column 4 Offset 0x20 Length 7 Length (physical) 7
v2 = 0x00f99f00b0350b
```

Comment: @Nick – When converting to `varbinary` SQL Server is adding the precision for the `datetime2` value. [The internal storage of a DATETIME2 value](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2010/12/15/the-internal-storage-of-a-datetime2-value.aspx)

Comment: @Mikael, that great, since I know the precision I can stripe that byte out before packing the value and add it in the unpacking process! Thanks a lot Mikael!!! :)

Comment: Why do you need to pack these values into a single varbinary column? As Damien rightly pointed out, you may have gleaned an understanding of how it works, but maybe a bigger question is why are you doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Good day,

firstly i want to say that this is the best question : "I don't know why you think that's a valid test anyway", since the answer is that **this is not valid test**!

You can read all about the issue, including the explanation of DateTime2 real stored format, and why this is mistake to examine the result of "CONVERT to binary" and assume that this is the same as the actual stored data! It is not accurate in variable-length data like varchar or nvarchar and it is not accurate in DateTime2 as well. The only way to examine and get the real stored format is examine the data itself using DBCC PAGE.
http://ariely.info/Blog/tabid/83/EntryId/162/Examine-how-DateTime2-type-stored-in-the-data-file.aspx

**I hope this is useful :-)**